# Is it possible to use markers on street view in android Google maps API v2?

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view

I implemented the street view in my app and i want to see the map markers in street view, it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays `Android Google maps API v2` can´t add markers, this option is only available for iOS.

**Markers within Street View**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview#markers_within_street_view

Comment: you mentioned 'nowadays' placing markers on streetmaps is only available for iOS. Is this still the same case? I do not see any updates to the documentation since two years ago, but want to confirm if you had any better insight.

Answer (score 4):

It's **possible** to add markers to StreetView in Android  via a **custom** implementation.

You should put a transparent **SurfaceView** on top of your **StreetView**,

Pass  panorama.**setOnStreetViewPanoramaCameraChangeListener**(..) and 
panorama.**setOnStreetViewPanoramaCameraChangeListener**(..) to your surface view to update **camera position** and **location**.

Then calculate **distance** to the marker from your camera location, and **azimuth** from you to the marker.

Lastly calculate **projection** of those values to the screen - get view height, view width, etc. from your surface view, and **draw** your markers' bitmap to surface view's  **canvas**.

Save those **bitmaps** to a HashMap to avoid loading same bitmap multiple times. This will make your draw thread run much faster.
Later you will probably want to load markers' icons from your online source.

There's still going to be some delay and markers are going to tremble a bit, so smoothen their placement.

Don't forget to save your markers screen projection **left top right bottom** placement in a HashMap to implement click on markers.

You will then want to make them markers **clickable**.

override **onTouchEvent**( .. )  in SurfaceView.

Save the  position from the latest **motion event** in some field, then return **false** to pass the touch  event to the underlying StreetView.

Implement panorama.**setOnStreetViewPanoramaClickListener** ( .. ) in the upper level - **pass the click event** to the SurfaceView, and you will know your **click's x/y** position from the saved field.

Loop through your markers' saved On Screen Position HashMap to know whether some marker was **really clicked**, if yes - **return that event** to the final listener in the upper level, and you will know when **a marker was clicked**

Check out the **video** to look how it turned out for my project - it took me 3 days to implement this feature
[[android] street view custom marker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbEU_6k6q9k)

I can't provide code samples here, but be free to ask

Comment: Hey dude can you help me relating this issue